# Templating Run Configurations in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, run-configuration

I have multiple springboot apps that share the same environment variables.

I want to create and maintain common run configurations for all the apps (if possible) or atleast somehow make the run configurations use the same set of environment variables.

Intellij allows me to create templates for the run configurations which makes every new configuration created inherit those common values as default.

How can I achieve a similar thing within Eclipse?

Comment: In _Run > Run Configuration_ select _Java Application_ and hit _New launch configuration prototype_ button in the upper left.

Comment: But every new configuration created after prototype doesnt automatically associate to the prototype. You have to manually attach that.